# Without #import <Foundation/Foundation.h> statement how I am able to use it in my Iphone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I a new to Objective C and iphone development. I read somewhere that I need to import the header files of foundation framework in my files where I want to use them. But I saw a sample Iphone project which was using `NSString, NSDate, NSArray` etc but there was never a statement like `#import Foundation.h` or `#import NSString.h` or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at the supporting files there will be a file yourprojectname-Prefix.pch open that up..

there you will se something like...

```
//
// Prefix header for all source files of the 'yourProject' target in the 'yourProject' project
//

#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_3_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iPhone SDK 3.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

this is automatically added to your file.

Answer (score 2):

The import was probably in a [prefix header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_header). Prefix headers get added to the top of every file that gets compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the `Prefix.pch` file in the "Supporting files" folder in your project?